# How to deserialize associated value from url query in axum

Tags: rust, serde, rust-axum

To make this simple, I'm writing a simple Axum post request handler that takes a Query (to simplify), where SampleStruct is defined roughly as follows:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct QueryParams {
    example: Fruit,
    color: String,
}
```

where fruit is defined as follows:

```
enum fruit {
    banana(u8),
    apple,
}
```

However, when I try to send a post request formatted as both of the following I get errors:
...?example=banana(100)
`error: unknown variant 'banana(100)', expected one of 'banana', 'apple'`
...?example={"banana": 100}
`error: unknown variant '{"banana": 100}', expected one of 'banana', 'apple'`

I can't think of any other way to format the query parameter so that it properly deserializes. I also  couldn't find any help online already. If anybody has an idea, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Url query parameters don't have a set format besides `?key=value,...` so serde-urlencoded (the crate used by axum here) doesn't make any effort to handle complex values (arrays, nested structs, tuples, etc.). There is a competing serde-qs crate that is more accommodating, but I don't think it handles what you want either. You would probably need a custom deserialize implementation based on string parsing.